# $stateParams Query parameter undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I am trying to get the query parameters from my angular UI router application. However I cannot seem to get them when I use the query method. The state params are always coming through as undefined.

```
$stateProvider.state("message",
{
    views: {
        "main-view": {
            templateUrl: "admin/templates/message.html",
            controller: ["$scope", "$stateParams", function ($scope, $stateParams )
            {
                // Get the params
                $scope.message = $stateParams.message; // undefined
                $scope.error = $stateParams.status; // undefined
            }]
            }
        },                  
        url: "/admin/message?message&status"
     })
}
```

The URL i am using to access this state is:

```
http://localhost:8080/admin/message?message=hello&status=error
```

However if I use the Basic Parameters method it works fine. I.e:

```
url: "/admin/message/:message/:status"
...
http://localhost:8080/admin/message/hello/error
```

I have html5 mode activated (not sure if that affects it?)

My code has been simplified for the above - am I doing something wrong here? Have I forgot to include anything?

Thanks

Comment: Where have you seen that the `url: "/admin/message?message&status"` can be defined like that ? I only know of the other method which works for you. Why not use that?

Comment: Hi Omri - from the site it says you can do it like I did: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#query-parameters  I need to use query parameters as I am using a third party system that sends the data using a query string which I can't change